# GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.courses.courseWork.create failed with error: Internal error encountered

Tags: google-classroom

I can't understand why this piece of code suddenly returns internal error.
It was working like a charm, after a while it started to throw the error in header and there is nothing to do.

```
var courseWork = {  
      'title': 'Reglamento',  
      'description': 'Por favor, leer los documentos adjuntos.',  
      'materials': [  
        {'link': { 'url': linkDocumento }},
        {'link': { 'url': "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eESDk5HA3vR2IEbV0UglaR0F6UysuEmd/view?usp=sharing" }}
      ],
      'workType': 'ASSIGNMENT',
      // 'state': 'DRAFT',
      'state': 'PUBLISHED',
      'topicId': idTema
    }; 
    Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(courseWork, passa.idClasse);
```

Comment: Is it happening all the time? I have tried it and for me it worked with no issue. Does it happen with other courses or is it happening on the Try This from the [Method: courses.courseWork.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/create)?

Comment: Every month I  generate about 120 classrooms, after I insert in each one the course rules with the code above. Until yesterday I had no problem. Yesterday after the first 50 classroms (aprox) it started to give that error. I tried with different classroom in the list, but it's always the same. I tried as well to change from PUBLISHED to DRAFT and I generate a new classroom not in the list, I suppose it is something related to my account, but I can't understand it's impossible to understand with no info about the error.

Comment: Yes Kessy, the error comes from  the Method: courses.courseWork.create, the container is created with no problems, the error comes when the script inserts the documents in te container.

Comment: Have you tried it from the API documentation Try this as I mentioned on the previous comment?

Comment: Actually the problem was the document I was sharing. As I mentioned before, each month I generate 120 classrooms and in each one I put a document "Course Rules". This document is shared from my Drive account (Sharing rules is "Everyone that has the link can see"). Doing this the sistem charges to the document the link of each classroom that shares it and, I suppose, there is a limit in the number of links that a document can receive. With a new copy of the document no more error. The workaround will be to copy the document in the classroom drive folder and share it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the comments on the question:

> Actually the problem was the document I was sharing. As I mentioned before, each month I generate 120 classrooms and in each one I put a document "Course Rules". This document is shared from my Drive account (Sharing rules is "Everyone that has the link can see"). Doing this the system charges to the document the link of each classroom that shares it and, I suppose, there is a limit in the number of links that a document can receive.
>
> With a new copy of the document no more error. The workaround will be to copy the document in the classroom drive folder and share it from there.